# Equivalent of Qt qCompress in Java

Tags: java, qt

I have Qt based client-server application. The client app compresses data using `qCompress` call and the server uncompresses it using `qUncompress` method.

I now need to write a new client app in Java that communicates with the same server. For proper uncompressing, I need to ensure that I use the same compression as `qCompress` is doing.

Browsing the net, it appears Qt may be using zip compression. I looked at java zip related classes. However, I am not sure if it will work. For example, `ZipEntry` constructor requires a name as a parameter. However, Qt does not require any names as parameter.

I would appreciate it if you can confirm whether Java zip classes are compatible with Qt compression/uncompression. If they are compatible, what would be the value of my parameter to `ZipEntry` constructor? Regards.

Comment: I think that `qCompress` is compatible only with itself. It's basically `zlib` compressing (so you would need something like `java.util.zip.Inflater`), but it contains some incompatible changes (like a 4 bytes "length" header which is non standard). I think that if you check the source code as well as what those Java classes expect you can make it work with minor adaptations.

Comment: Rather `java.util.zip.Deflater`. Have you figured out? Just facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no library that I am aware however you can use `java.util.zip.Deflater` to compress the data and add the size of the uncompressed data in the beginning of the byte array:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;

final int MAX_DATA = 1024;
final int SIZE_LENGTH = 4;

// Input data
byte[] uncompressed = "hello".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

// This is simplistic, you should use a dynamic buffer
byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_DATA];

// Add the uncompressed data size to the first 4 bytes
ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, SIZE_LENGTH).putInt(uncompressed.length);

// Compress it
Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
deflater.setInput(uncompressed);
deflater.finish();
// Write past the size bytes when compressing
int size = deflater.deflate(buffer, SIZE_LENGTH, buffer.length - SIZE_LENGTH);
// TODO maybe check the returned size value to increase the buffer size?
if (!deflater.finished()) throw new DataFormatException("Buffer size exceeded");

// Compressed data that can be consumed by qUncompress
byte[] compressed = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, SIZE_LENGTH + size);
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is doing a qCompress on the client side and sending to a java app. This helper function may help you decompress it. Please note the comment - I am using it to handle POST data so I can't trust the data telling me what size it is.

```
/** This takes data sent from Qt's qCompress and decompresses it.
* Note that we don't use the first 4 bytes (which is the size of the decompressed data) to avoid someone crafting
* a message which says the decompressed data is 2^32-1 even when it's not.
* @param input The raw bytearray containing the whole output from qCompress
* @return The decompressed data
* @throws IOException
* @throws DataFormatException
*/
public static byte[] qUncompress(byte[] input) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
  Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
  inflater.setInput(input, 4, input.length - 4); //Strip off the first 4 bytes - this is a non standard uncompressed size that qCompress adds.
  ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(input.length);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
  while (!inflater.finished()) {
     int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
     outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
  }
  outputStream.close();
  return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```